# Which font can I use to support all scripts (latin, kanji, cyrillic etc), for iPhone?

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

Is there a font that supports all scripts? Ideally and "Apple" font, so I can use it in my iOS app without having to pay royalties.

I will use it in a UILabel.

Thanks,
Pieter

Comment: Are you saying that I do not need to set the font? I'm wondering what the actual name of the font is, incase I decide to use something besides the UILabel that doesn't automatically use the system font.

Comment: the font is literally called the 'system font', and so long as you are on an iOS device, it is the default font for everything, ergo you neednt worry about it not being available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, iOS handles diacritic languages itself, and the iOS keyboard is quite robust when it comes to accented characters in the standard system font.  Xcode even supports the copying and pasting of most (if not all) of these characters directly into string literals.

*tl;dr* Use the system font. (`[UIFont systemFontOfSize:mySize];`)